# Determine if a column has a certain text value after cell loses focus in datagridview control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Lets say column[0] header text equals "Jim". I need the message box to show when cell belonging to Jim's column loses focus.

```
private void estimateDataGridView_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ColumnHeader1"].Value.ToString() == "Jim")
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Jim is the value of column 1");
  }
}
```

Using the code above I get the following runtime exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can someone please explain why the question is getting negative feedback so I can edit it and get an answer.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the question, have voted up accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly right, you are just handling the wrong event (and missing a semicolon).

When `CellLeave` fires, the content of the cell you are leaving isn't updated yet. You want to handle `CellValueChanged`.

Comment: I have tried this handle but for some reason when I debug the form never loads the output window is normal as if the form will load but it never does.

Comment: Then you have bigger problems which are not at all indicated in your example.